# How to apply a templatetags filter on a simple templatetags return

Tags: django, filter, templatetags

In my template, I use a custom simple_tag this called myTag and taking two args :

```
{% myTag arg1 arg2 %}
```

It returns me a string.

I would like to use the truncatewords built-in templatetags filter on the return but I can't find the correct syntax ...

To sum-up, I want something like :

```
<h1>{% myTag arg1 arg2 %}|truncatewords:2</h1>
```

Comment: You would have to apply the filter to the output of the template tag.

Comment: You mean, in the templatetag itself? Is there no way to apply it on the return in the template ?

Comment: No, because you have to evaluate the filter: `{% {% myTag arg1 arg2 %}|truncatewords:2 %}` which won't work.

Comment: Template filters are just functions. You can call them anywhere in your Python code. Since you're writing a custom tag, what is your objection to adding the filter to the output of the tag? It's infinitely easier and also makes it re-usable. Additionally, you could pass an extra argument to your tag that could conditionally apply the truncation, or even how many words to truncate on.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use an [assignment-tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead.

then you could do:

```
{% myTag arg1 arg2 as answer %}
{{ answer|truncatewords:2 }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, running on django 1.3